# The icon change after expand in Jstree

Tags: javascript, jstree

I have the icon from font awesome.

```
<li data-jstree='{"icon":"fa fa-envelope-o"}'>
    <span id="id">Description</span>
    <ul>
        <li data-jstree='{"disabled":true}'>
        <span id="id">Documents</span>
       </li> 
    </ul>
</li>
```

[image]

and when I open the node, the icon change to it's original state.

[image]

I have the problem with only 'fa fa-envelope-o', if I test with anoter like 'fa fa-envelope-open-o' it's work.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this solution, maybe there is a better way.

```
$('#TreeId').on("close_node.jstree", function (e,data) {    
    setTimeout(function(){
    $("#" + data.node.id).find('i').eq(1).removeClass('fa-minus-circle fa-plus-circle');        
    }, 1);
});
```